# MongoDB collection field compare with Current date to get the active users count in a day

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

```
var dt= new Date();
var datestring = dt.getFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+dt.getDate()).slice(-2);
db.getCollection('Profile Section').count({Last_Active : {$regex : datestring}})
```

I have written this query in Mongo DB, It is giving correct count value. So I have written Query properly. I am using Spring Boot for backend, how can I create this query equivalent to JAVA, I am using rest API to call in postman application, 
Can u suggest how can I write equivalent spring boot backend with the help of this query? and also I have to insert resultant count value to another collection called ActiveUsers in mongodb.

`@GetMapping("/Activeusers")`
is the api call in my JAVA application.

Comment: I suspect the naming convention `db.getCollection('Profile')`. Are you sure it's a valid database name?

Comment: Yes, Profile is correct collection name

Comment: For how long would an active user be considered as active? 1 minutes, 2 minutes?

Comment: Time duration we have mentioned, we are calculating active users, by matching with current date. session duration we are not considering

Comment: Where did you mention it? `new Date()` would give you the precision of milliseconds.

Comment: ... and if you query 1 millisecond after the user was stored as an "active user", you won't get this result. Chances are really low to get a result. Hence, I would recommend you to take a small time interval, of a few seconds for example. If you are interested in a solution like this, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: @TechWisdom please post the answer, I will look into it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @TechWisdom, also I need to fetch LastActive field from Profile collection, and compare with current date, if LastActive date field is match with current date, then I need to increment the counter value, then counter value I need to store in ActiveUsers collection.  I am using Spring Boot for backend, can u please help me for this.

Comment: @PrasadMayyaM I posted an answer. Regarding your second question, please edit your question and provide your code. Also, explain what is your intent, because it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$gte` & `$lt` query commands.

```
db.getCollection('Profile').find({
    "lastActive" : {
        $gte: new Date('2020-05-19'),
        $lt: new Date('2020-05-20'),
    }
}).pretty()
```

In Spring,

```
@Query("{'lastActive' : { $gte: ?0, $lt: ?1 } }")
public List<Profile> getProfileByLastActive(LocalDate today, LocalDate nextDay);
```

Use either LocalDate or Date as per your convenience.

If you are going to implement in Node.js, the best option is to use `moment.js`. Actually I have been working with moment.js for calendar related activities. That's y I am suggesting to use it.

Comment: But I am using Spring Boot

Comment: Updated the answer, pls give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is accurate. The problem: it's too much accurate.

If you were to update those records every millisecond, you would be able to get them. But this is an overkill for most usages, and this is where the architecture of your system matters.

Querying a date field with an `$eq` operator, will fetch results with an exact match, with a milliseconds precision. The "active users" logic might attempt us to check users who are active right now, and imply our intuition to use an `$eq` operator. While this is correct, we will miss lots of users who are active, but their corresponding records on db are not updated at the millisecond rate (and this depends on the way you update your db records).

As implied above, one solution would be to update the db, with dozens of updates just to have an accurate description on db for a kind of real time active users manner. This might be too much for many systems.

Another solution would be to query the active users by an interval / gap of few seconds (or more). Every second would increase the probability of getting active users by a factor of 1,000. You can see this here:

```
db.getCollection('Profile').find({"lastActive" : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 2)}}).pretty() // this fetch records within 2 seconds
```